# datetime.date.today() always returns the same value

Tags: python, django, datetime, gunicorn

I have a Django project. I use nginx + gunicorn.
The views.py file has a combined_data() function that creates and returns an HTML page. As you can see, I am passing the objects in 'rows' and the current date in 'time'.

[image]

A function that returns objects looks like this

[image]

The problem is that in this function, reporting_date always gets the value it got the first time it was called.
For example, I do "sudo systemctl restart gunicorn" and open this page in the browser. reporting_date will be equal to today. If I open the page tomorrow, reporting_date will not change its value.

Initially, I assumed that datetime.date.today () does not work correctly, so I added the 'time' parameter to views.py (first screen), but the date is always correct there.
Then I thought that the default value of the parameters of the get_combined() function (second screen) is somehow cached, so I added the r_int parameter, which receives a random value, but everything works correctly here. r_int always gets a new value.

Now, I have to call "sudo systemctl restart gunicorn" every day to make the page work properly ((

Any ideas how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: try `datetimie.datetime.now()`

Comment: @KillerRebooted Of course, I can try it and find out the result tomorrow, but I would like to understand why, with such an implementation, everything works like that. what is the problem?

Comment: I found a solution, actually i just checked, my previous suggestion doesn't work either. See the answer

Comment: When you declare a default value for a function parameter it is evaluated once and **not** every time the function is called

Comment: @OldBill , Why, then, does the second parameter 'r_int' always get a new value?

Comment: @VladAdrian It won't. You are mistaken. Please show code that you allege reproduces the issue

Comment: @OldBill Look at the second screen, there is an r_int parameter that receives a random value. On the same screen, I do print(r_int) and each time I get a new value in the logs. Accordingly, in the case of r_int, the default value is calculated every time (at least in my case) when the function is called. I specifically added this parameter to check if the values are not cached. If I had received the same value, I would not have posted this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
def get_combined(reported_date=datetime.datetime.today()):
```

use

```
def get_combined():
    reported_date = datetime.datetime.today()
```

What I tried:-

```
>>> def c(day = datetime.today()):
        print(day)

    
>>> c()
>>> 2022-10-27 15:44:57.593444
>>> c()
>>> 2022-10-27 15:44:57.593444
```

```
>>> def c():
        day = datetime.today()
        print(day)

    
>>> c()
>>> 2022-10-27 15:56:02.459517
>>> c()
>>> 2022-10-27 15:56:04.630902
```

As @OldBill mentioned: When you declare a default value for a function parameter it is evaluated once and not every time the function is called

Comment: This will break calls that do not pass an argument. Instead, `reported_date` should have a default value of `None`, and then inside `reported_date = reported_date or datetime.datetime.today()`

Answer (score 2):

The default value for the parameter `reported_date` is the value of the first time the function gets imported. You should do something like

```
def get_combined(reported_date=None, ...):
    reported_date = reported_date or datetime.datetime.today()
    ...
```